# Transition property not working on hover of parent element

Tags: html, css

I am trying to apply transition on a child element when the parent element is hovered. The transition is not working as expected.

When I change the transition function from linear to ease-in-out it works once. Then the visibility is instantaneous. The CSS is applied as expected on inspecting the elements in the console.

Here is my HTML

```
import React from 'react'
import '../MainLayout/MainLayout.css'
const MainLayout = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <div className='title-wrapper'>
                <div style={{display:'flex', flexDirection:'column' }}>
                    <p className='title-heading'>Let's</p>
                    <p className='title-heading-middle'>Animate</p>
                    <p className='title-heading'>using CSS</p>
                </div>
                <div className='scroll-items'>
                    <div className='item' />
                    <div className='item' />
                    <div className='item' />
                    <div className='item' />
                    <div className='item' />
                    <div className='item' />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default MainLayout
```

Here is my CSS

```
.title-wrapper {
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    max-height: fit-content;
}

.title-wrapper::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -5;
    background: dodgerblue;
    transition: transform 0.4s ease;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    transform-origin: right;
}

.title-wrapper:hover::before {
    transform: scaleX(1);
    transform-origin: left;
}

.title-wrapper:hover .title-heading {
    color: white;
}
.title-wrapper:hover .title-heading-middle {
    color: white;
}
.scroll-items {
    margin: 1rem;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    min-width: 400px;
    min-height: 100%;
    transition: opacity 0.5s, linear;
}

.title-wrapper:hover .scroll-items {
    visibility: visible;
    opacity: 1;
}

.item{
    background-image: url('../../assets/animate.jpg');
    margin: 5px;
}
```

I want to make the `scroll-items` visible on hover of the `title-wrapper` with a transition.

Comment: You go from visible -> hidden, so it's gonna go invisible the moment you unhover the element. it works the other way cause you make it visible and then the opacity transition can make it show

Comment: I tried is by setting the visibility to visible in the element. And transition only on the opacity using the hover of the parent element. It is still not showing the transition property effect.